# Wallaby.js not working for Sublime 3

Tags: angular, sublimetext3, wallaby.js

I'm trying to use Wallaby.js in Sublime for an Angular project.

I've installed the package, but when I 'Start' wallaby, nothing displays.

Anyone have experience with this config and wallaby?

Update: I'm developing on a mac. I've scaffolded my project with @angular/cli.

Comment: We don't know what is going on your local machine :)

Comment: @yurzui - Added this update: I'm developing on a mac. I've scaffolded my project with @angular/cli.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example reproducing your issue?

Comment: @yurzui - I'm not sure what I can provide, as this is not a code issue I'm having. The environment is Angular, with basic cli scaffolding. The IDE is Sublime with a package install of Wallaby. Angular CLI automatically creates a spec file for unit testing, so any spec file should display the Wallaby visual feedback.

Comment: Checking wallaby console for reported errors may help: https://wallabyjs.com/docs/intro/get-started-sublime.html#troubleshooting